# How can I make setInterval increase each time when user clicks?

Tags: javascript, html

This is from JavaScript for kids, and I am stuck. How can I make `setInterval` increase each time the user clicks on the header? I have tried several solutions such as `setInterval(moveheading,counter)` or creating multiple `setIntervals` but it always seems to choose the fastest one and then proceeds to lose the second slowest (creating the opposite desired effect).

I have read that maybe `setTimeOut` would be a better solution to this, but I am having a hard time figuring out how. The book 'JavaScript for kids' can be found online as a PDF if you need further reference. The page where this challenge is at is 166.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>


<head>
    <title>MouseMove</title>
</head>

<body>
    <h1 id='heading'> Try and click me 10 times.</h1>

    <script src='https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.js'></script>

    <script>
        var leftOffset = 0;
        var topOffset = (200, 0);
        var rightOffset = 200;
        var toTheTop = (0, 200);
        var counter = 10;
        var congrats = "Congrats you Win!"


        var moveHeading = function() {


            $('#heading').offset({
                top:0,
                left: leftOffset
            });
            leftOffset++;


            if (leftOffset > 200) {


                $('#heading').offset({
                   top: topOffset,
                    left: 200

                });
                topOffset++;


            }
            if (topOffset > 200) {
                 $('#heading').offset({
                     left:rightOffset,
                     top: 200

            });
           rightOffset--                           

            };
             if (rightOffset < 0) {
                $('#heading').offset({
                 left:(200,0),
                    top:toTheTop


                });
                toTheTop--;
             }

           <p> ijfsdkfjnlskdjfklsdjfs</P>

        if (toTheTop < 0){
      leftOffset = 0,
        topOffset = (200, 0),
         rightOffset = 200,
          toTheTop= (200);


            }


        };

   var ghost = function () {
       $("#heading").text(counter)
       counter--;
   }


     var chill =function ()  {

  if (counter < 7 )
        clearInterval(nuts);}


    var nuts = setTimeout(moveHeading,1000)

  $("#heading").click(moveHeading)
         $("#heading").click(ghost)

        $("#heading").click(chill);
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why you can make settimeout as setinterval,

```js
function function1(time) {
    console.log("Time is :" + time); // run this it is actually funny
}
let x;
function runner(time) {
    function1(time);
    x = setTimeout(function() {
        runner(1000);
    }, time);
    clearTimeout(x); // Comment out this clear timeout and see the output
}

runner(100);
```

try this type of solution

Comment: I am really knew to this whole coding thing. How can I apply the above mentioned formula to what I already have. I did try but still no success

Answer (score -1):

To set different (dynamic) duration, we need to stop the current timer, using `clearInterval()`, then re-run the timer with the new counter.